# In the bot framework OAuth Flow with Teams, what is the correct way to consent to changed permissions?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

I've implemented the OAuth flow in a Teams bot similar to the [sample](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/46.teams-auth), and I'm able to get a user token and make calls against the graph, but I'm running into an issue with changing permissions.  Here's what I did:

- Created a bot and gave it mail.read
- Add the bot for a user and trigger the OAuth dialog.  User is prompted for consent, and signed in.
- Successfully read mail
- In AAD, added the Mail.ReadWrite and Mail.Send permissions to the app
- Next time the OAuthPrompt was triggered, token was returned immediately.  No prompt for consent.
- Got an access denied exception when trying to write or send mail

So the issue is that changing permissions on the app does not automatically trigger the consent flow again in the OAuthPrompt.  I also tried these troubleshooting steps:

- I manually signed the user out (botAdapter.SignOutUserAsync) and signed back in, but was not prompted for consent again.
- Same as above, but signed out of Teams as well.  Launched the web client in a new incognito window, and still no prompt for consent.
- Uninstalled and re-installed the bot on the user's account.  No change.
- Tried the above after waiting a few hours, but still no change.

The only way I found to trigger the consent flow again was to have the user go to https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/applications and delete the consent from there.  Even then I had to call botAdapter.SignOutUserAsync (since the bot service still returned a token with the old permissions).  Once I did that, and triggered the OAuth prompt again, I was able to get the consent flow with the new permissions to trigger.

So my question is, is there a better way to handle this?  If a new version of the bot requires new permissions, shouldn't the OAuthPrompt from Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs and the bot service handle re-prompting for consent?

Comment: In your Azure bot registration, for the OAuth connection setting, are you using "Azure Active Directory v2"? If so, did you update the scopes listed in that connection setting before calling `SignOutUserAsync` and signing back in?

Comment: No, just a standard Azure AD listing with no scopes as detailed in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample).  That was specific about V1 and nothing in scopes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

Bot Framework's auth provider for AAD v1 isn't flexible enough to support adding scopes.

You can switch to the AAD v2 provider and specify your new scopes in the OAuth Connection Settings. Then, if you force the user to sign in again (after `SignOutUserAsync`), you will get a consent screen including the new scopes. To set up the AAD v2 provider, see the Bot Framework docs on [adding authentication to a bot](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-authentication?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=aadv2%2Ccsharp), which has steps for both the AAD v1 and AAD v2 providers.

### Long answer

The key to this behavior is how the AAD v1 and AAD v2 endpoints handle permissions and consent differently.

#### The problem with v1

In v1, the permissions (such as `Mail.Send`) are pre-registered in the AAD app registration. During sign-in, AAD checks if the user has already consented to *any scopes* for the app.

- If yes, AAD skips the consent screen and eventually provides an access token *for the scopes that had already been consented*.
- If no, AAD shows the consent screen *for all registered scopes* and eventually provides an access token *for all of those scopes*.

This explains the behavior you're seeing. After you tell Bot Framework to forget the current access token (via `SignOutUserAsync`) and force the user to login again, AAD sees that the user has consented previously, so it skips the consent screen and gives you a new token with the old scopes.

Then how do you add permissions for users who have already consented, without forcing the user to delete consent for the app? AAD's login endpoint has an [optional `prompt` parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#request-an-authorization-code) that you can set to `prompt=consent`. This will force AAD to show the consent screen as if the user had not previously consented, and it will contain all registered permissions. So if you try to use an access token and get a `403 Forbidden` error (or an equivalent exception), you can take the user through the login flow using `prompt=consent`.

Unfortunately, with Azure Bot Service's AAD v1 provider, you don't have enough control over the login URL to dynamically set the `prompt` parameter, so there isn't an easy way to achieve this.

#### Enter v2

But there's hope! The AAD v2 endpoints have a much more flexible way of [adding scopes incrementally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/azuread-dev/azure-ad-endpoint-comparison#incremental-and-dynamic-consent). In v2, for delegated permissions, the permissions do *not* have to be pre-registered in the AAD app registration. Instead, you specify the scopes in the `scope` parameter of the login URL. During sign-in, AAD checks if the user has consented to *the scopes you specified in the URL*.

- If yes, AAD skips the consent screen and eventually provides an access token *for the scopes you specified*.
- If no, AAD shows the consent screen *for all the scopes you specified* and eventually provides an access token *for all of those scopes*.

Either way, you end up with an access token containing all the scopes you specified in the URL.

Bot Framework sets the `scope` parameter using the scopes you specify in the OAuth Connection Settings. So if you add a new scope there, then the next time the user signs in, they will get a consent screen with the new permissions, and you will get an access token with the new scopes. (Note: To re-trigger the sign-in, you will still have to sign the user out using `SignOutUserAsync`. Otherwise, Bot Framework will continue giving you the access token it already has, instead of performing a new sign-in flow with AAD.)

Comment: Thanks-that seems to work actually.  I think the issue is that the Teams-specific version of that [docs page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/authentication/add-authentication?tabs=dotnet%2Cdotnet-sample) specifically calls out V1.  Seems like V2 works without any other underlying changes.  Question though-having to force a sign out/sign in on the user end is definitely not ideal-is there a point where the bot framework will pick up the scope changes and force a re-consent on its own?

Comment: So it doesn't look like the framework handles this internally, but I managed to handle it in my bot by keeping track of the scopes I expect, and comparing the scopes in the claim to the ones I expect.  If there's something missing, I force the sign out and reprompt.

Comment: @ChrisBardon That works. Alternatively you could check for `403 Forbidden` responses, though depending on your scenario, maybe there are other valid reasons for getting a 403. I'm not on the Bot Framework team, so I can't speak to whether scope changes will ever be handled by Azure Bot Service, but in my opinion, that should be left to the developer, because adding scopes doesn't always mean you require those scopes and need to force relogin. I encourage you to post the feature request on GitHub so the maintainers/community can weigh in: https://github.com/microsoft/botbuilder-dotnet/issues